# Organising TableViewController custom functions into separate files

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I am a noob in programming, I have a `UITableViewController` with about 12 `Sections` and each `Section` has only one `Cell` and each `Cell` contains about 15-18 input field of almost all types (e.g. `UITextField`, `UIPickerView`, `UIDatePicker`, `UISwitch` ...).

in the last `Cell` I've put a `Button` as my save button for all the above fields (still didn't try it if it works).

But anyway, I just finished the first `Section` and I already have so many `IBOutlets` and `IBActions`.

I have a feeling that this is not the right way to do it and I should make it cleaner. Because if I get back to fix something in future it'll be too confusing.

How can I add the codes of each `Section` into one `Swift` file so that for each `Section` I have a file that contains all `IBOutlets` and `functions`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some code to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create individual files for each TableViewCell, if you are using different types of cells and then you can add those IBOutlets into the related TableViewCell file.

Comment: Thank you, I added the outlets to a TableViewCell file. but there's a problem now: I had an object of my custom class "Product" and in this TableView I was populating the fields with this object (such as price, article name etc...) but now how can I populate this fields (which are now in a different file) and vice versa? 
because I also need to get the input fields in my main TableViewController file in order to modify the data or save it. I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: I got how to do it